# Find files in Mac OS X by permissions setting?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, find, file-permissions

I recently needed to restore my Mac (10.6.8 v1.1) from a backup and while the machine is stable and intact, a scattering of files have incorrect permissions in my user account which is interfering with some operations.

I have looked through directories manually in the Finder and corrected those I have seen but I would like to search the user directory for files whose permissions does not include me (admin).

Is there a tool or command that searches a directory on the basis of a permissions setting in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Terminal.app and enter the following to find all files you are not the owner of:

```
find ~ ! -user danielbeck
```

(If your username is `danielbeck` — run `whoami` to find out your user name)

You can use the `-group groupname` argument similarly, but you should be the *owner* of most files in your home directory first to have everything work well.

---

Or, to make you the owner of all files in your home directory:

```
sudo chown -R danielbeck ~
```

I don't recommend this if you use FileVault. It's a bit of a sledgehammer method. Try searching first.

Comment: That is fantastic, terminal returned a list which I can use to fix the ones that remain. Many thanks.